# How to use user permissions with Facebook C# SDK

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Does someone know how we can use [permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) with [Facebook C# SDK](http://csharpsdk.org/)?

I mean to pass a list of permissions via Facebook C# SDK?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need permissions only to get token. That's always achieved with client-side javascript, not with C# backend code. Look here - http://csharpsdk.org/docs/web/getting-started - see **Requesting an Access Token from a Website** section. It shows how to request token with certain permissions from the JavaScript code. After that token is granted, and passed back to the backend - that's where you can start using it with C# SDK - doing things like posting to the feed, uploading images etc - but you won't do anything with permissions on the backend.

Comment: Thanks! I use WPF application project. No Java Script.  Do u know how I can do it with Facebook C# SDK?

Comment: if you have token you got from somewhere else - then you can start using C# SDK. If not - then you should open facebook login form in a webbrowser control: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/ - see the first URL - that's where you have to specify list of permissions you are requesting. After user logs in, you will get access token back.