# Get members id of private facebook group

Tags: facebook, winforms, c#-4.0, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I want to get the members id of private facebook groups using facebook api and c#. i can get users id of open facebook group please any idea.

```
        var fb = new FacebookClient(AccessToken);

        //var query = string.Format("select name from group where gid = {0}", name);
        var query = string.Format("select uid from group_member where gid = {0}", gid);
        //dynamic rest = fb.Get("167899503240064/members");

        dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
        parameters.q = query;

        dynamic result = fb.Get("/fql", parameters);
       // JObject GroupListJson = JObject.Parse(result.ToString()); 

        var r1 = (from i in (IEnumerable<dynamic>)result.data
         select new
         {

             i.id
         });
```

Answer (score 1):

> #### Permissions
>
> To read the `group_member` table you need:
>
> - any valid access_token if the group is public (i.e. the group's privacy setting is OPEN)
> - `user_groups` permission for a user's non-public groups or to see the bookmark_order
>     or unread fields for a user's groups
> - `friends_groups` permission for a
>     user's friend's non-public groups

Previous to the query, you need to request the `user_groups` permission.

To get this working, please start from here: [How to use user permissions with Facebook C# SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10690067/how-to-use-user-permissions-with-facebook-c-sharp-sdk)